# How to toggle between booleans (in a list or tuple)?

Tags: python, boolean

```py
i = True
j = False
t = (i,j)
for i in t:
    if i:
        i = not i
        
print (t)
(True, False)
```

For example, I want to change all values in a tuple to False, no matter the element was True or False before. How can I realise that?

Comment: Tuples are immutable. You need to create a new Tuple with the right values.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with a list comprehension:

```py
t = [False for _ in t]
```

or

```py
t = tuple(False for _ in t)
```

if you want a tuple.

Your method doesn’t work because (imprecisely) `i = not i` does not change the value of `i`, it makes a new `i`, with a different value, so the ‘original’ value in your tuple is unaffected.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a new Tuple.

In fact it seems you need a Tuple with only False in it:

```py
i = True
j = False
t = (i,j)
t = Tuple([False] * len(t))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
i = True
j = False
t = (i,j)
result = ()
for i in range(len(t)):
    result = result + (False,)

print(result)
```